# Angular: Current page link is not reloading page contents

Tags: angular, codeigniter

I have one route like this: `list/:id/:name`.

Here 'list' is page slug and `id` and `name` are dynamic value of url.

When I click on button to go to mentioned url then it opens fine. Codeigniter controller function gives data via api to the angular and all data displaying correctly.

But on same page, there are many links whose slug (`list`) is same but dynamic value (`id`, 'name') is different.

for example:- url: `"list/3/dummyname"`, url: `"list/5/dummynametwo"` and so on.

When I click on those links, then url changes but page's content remains same. Here is how I am calling page links

```
goToList(list_id, list_name) {
this.util.publishHeader({ header: false, total: this.allRest.length, active: this.activeFilter });
this.router.navigate(['list', parseInt(lsit_id), list_name.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase()]);
}
```

Above ts function is used to redirect to url.

If I go to this url via any other url then it works find but if on same page (`list`) I click on link which redirects to same page but with different dynamic value then it only changes url, not page's content.

Why only url is changing, not page's content?

Comment: The Component is the same, So Angular can not know if some has changed. Generally you subscribe in ngOnInit to this.route.paramMap to know when the parameters has changed, see the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/router#accessing-query-parameters-and-fragments)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code on the constructor of your component.

```
constructor(private router: Router) {
   this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = function () {
      return false;
   };
}
```